# Extract certain keys of script content with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have extracted the content of a certain script with "BeautifulSoup". The content of the script contains "json-like" structured data.

I want to extract the three "urls" of the first "content" group and the "defeatedBosses" from the second "content" group.

**This is the extracted script content (part of):**

```
new WH.Wow.TodayInWow(WH.ge('tiw-standalone'), [{
    "id": "dungeons-and-raids",
    "groups": [{
        "content": {
            "lines": [{
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "url": "\/affix=9\/tyrannical"
            }, {
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "url": "\/affix=3\/volcanic"
            }, {
                "icon": "spell_shadow_bloodboil",
                "url": "\/affix=8\/sanguine"
            }],
            "icons": "large"
        },
        "id": "mythicaffix",
    }, {
        "content": {
            "defeatedBosses": 9,
        },
        "id": "mythic-progression",
        "url": "\/aberrus-the-shadowed-crucible\/overview"
    }, 

    ...
```

**And my Python (3.11) script so far:**

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

req = Request('https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script_sp = all_scripts[36]

// My try

model_data = re.search(r"content = ({.*?});", script_sp, flags=re.S)
model_data = model_data.group(1)

model_data = json.loads(model_data)

print(model_data)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'Tag'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can download the page, parse the required data and print sample imformation (info about US Dungeons&Raids):

```py
import re
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')

json_data = re.search(r"TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('tiw-standalone'\), (.*), true\);", html_page)
json_data = json.loads(json_data.group(1))

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

for part in json_data:
    if part['id'] == 'dungeons-and-raids' and part['regionId'] == 'US':
        for g in part['groups']:
            print(g['name'], g.get('url', '-'))
```

Prints:

```
Mythic+ Affixes /guides/mythic-keystones-and-dungeons
Aberrus, the Shadowed Crucible (Mythic) https://www.wowhead.com/guide/raids/aberrus-the-shadowed-crucible/overview
Conquest Points -
```

---

EDIT: For easier search I recommend to transform the Json data from a list to a dictionary:

```py
import re
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request(
    "https://www.wowhead.com/today-in-wow", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
)
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")

json_data = re.search(
    r"TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('tiw-standalone'\), (.*), true\);", html_page
)
json_data = json.loads(json_data.group(1))

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

# transform the received data from list to a dictionary (for easier search)
data = {
    (d["id"], d["regionId"]): {dd["id"]: dd for dd in d["groups"]} for d in json_data
}

for line in data[("dungeons-and-raids", "US")]["mythicaffix"]['content']['lines']:
    l = line['name'], line['url']
    if line['name'] == 'Tyrannical':
        print(' --> ', *l)
    else:
        print('     ', *l)
```

Prints:

```
 -->  Tyrannical /affix=9/tyrannical
      Volcanic /affix=3/volcanic
      Sanguine /affix=8/sanguine
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps me a lot. One last question. I've tried to get `"url": "\/affix=9\/tyrannical"`, which means I need to go "two-levels" (groups->content->lines) deeper. This was my try: 
`for part in json_data:
    if part['id'] == 'dungeons-and-raids' and part['regionId'] == 'US':
        for g in part['groups']['content']['lines']:
            print(g['url'])` 
Could you give me an example of that, too?

Answer (score 2):

> Gives error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'Tag'

You should call [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the child is made available as .string:

```py
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script_sp = all_scripts[36].string
```

Also, I have fixed your regex to:

```py
model_data = re.search(r"new WH\.Wow\.TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('tiw-standalone'\), (\[.*?\](?=\, true\);))", script_sp, flags=re.S)
```

Prints a ton of JSON data.

To get the actual desired values, I'll leave it up to you, as its too much JSON to find the correct path :)